# correios frete gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-service

Olá, estou usando esse cálculo no controller porém quando coloco `<%= @pac %>` ou `<%= @sedex %>` na view não está mostrando o valor, alguém está tendo o mesmo problema?

grato

```
def calculate_ship
frete = Correios::Frete::Calculador.new :cep_origem => "23970-000",
:cep_destino => params[:post_code]
servicos = frete.calcular :sedex, :pac
@pac = servicos[:pac].valor
@sedex = servicos[:sedex].valor
redirect_to checkout_order_path
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está fazendo um `redirect_to` ao final. Isso faz com que seja feito uma nova requisição ao servidor e os valores são perdidos.
Você precisa substituir por algo como `render 'checkout'`.

Comment: é isso mesmo, obrigado pela dica Gui.